# update local storage value on change of particular item through out the application in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`

In the login method where user authentication takes place. I call a service `auth` to store the token and also fetch logged-in user profile info and store in the local storage all at the same time, then redirect to the allowed page.

This is how my login method is

```
loginUser() {
    const email = this.loginForm.value.username;
    const password = this.loginForm.value.password;

    this.auth.getAuthToken(email, password).subscribe(response => {

        // User is authenticated, save response access token credentials
        // in local storage using Auth Service
        this.auth.setCredentials(response);

        /**
         * Get user profile
         */
        this.account.getProfile().subscribe(
            res => {
                // Store user info to local storage
                this.auth.setProfileInfo(res);
            }
        );

        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']).then();

    });
}
```

I do this because profile info contains the logged in user name, avatar and other details and I use few of them to display in the navigation element with the avatar.

Now, I have few other components for the logged in user to make changes to his profile info like different component to change avatar, another one to change the name, etc.

In every component, I'm using the value stored in the local storage to display in the UI.

But whenever profile info is changed, I need to store updated profile info to local storage manually so that It could be reflected everywhere.

**Is there any way I can trigger a custom change event and have a service to listen to it and save the updated info to local storage automatically?**

> Edit 2

Even updating value in local storage is not updating in navigation html content. Changes are reflected after refreshing the page.

Comment: Have you tried using `BehaviorSubject` or a `Subject`? https://blog.angulartraining.com/rxjs-subjects-a-tutorial-4dcce0e9637f

Answer (score -1):

How do you even access the data from localstorage? Normal localstorage data is just to hold data for when user reopens your application. Else you hold it in service and once value in service is changed you apply that value in localstorage (but just to have it in backup, not to constantly read from it.

I solved this using observables. 
You have a base trigger observable. And once that observable is triggered I fetch data that I want to refresh.

```js
@LocalStorage()
storageValue: YourData;

profileChanged$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

userProfile$ = profileChanged$.pipe(
  startWith(this.storageValue)
  switchMap(() => getDataObservable()),
  tap(res => this.storageValue = res)
  share()
);

// and then in login
login() {
  // PREVIOUS AUTH
  
  this.profileChanged$.next(true);

}
```

You subscribe to that observable data where you want to display it using async pipe or subscription in your component.

That decorator is just to automatically save your value to localstorage. You can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage

Basically what this does is:

1. value to hold localstorage value - storageValue
2. triggerObservable to refetch data
3. pipeing trigger: first startWith cache data, refresh data, new data save to storage, and using share() this becomes a hot observable (there are [cold and hot observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339))
4. In login just trigger first triggerObservable to refetch data. You could call this trigger everywhere you need it aswell.